# Laravel 4.2 doesn't seem to read package's config files

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm getting this error during a belongsToMany relationship:

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
HELP
Array to string conversion
```

I'm using Entrust (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/1.0) for my user roles and permissions. When I do a Config::get('app.url'), it returns everything fine. I noticed however that the config in entrust is returning as a blank array which it shouldn't be. My code worked fine until I ran a composer update and nothing changed in Entrust.

This code in particular is returning the blank array:

```
php
$baseTable = $this->related->getTable();
```

It's line 360 in the BelongsToMany.php file in Laravel. EntrustRole.php sets it's protected $table property in the constructor by doing this:

```
php
$this->table = Config::get('entrust::roles_table');
```

In it's config file, there is this:

```
php
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Role Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the Role model used by Entrust to create correct relations.  Update
    | the role if it is in a different namespace.
    |
    */
    'role' => '\Role',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Roles Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the Roles table used by Entrust to save roles to the database.
    |
    */
    'roles_table' => 'roles',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Permission Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the Permission model used by Entrust to create correct relations.  Update
    | the permission if it is in a different namespace.
    |
    */
    'permission' => '\Permission',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Permissions Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the Permissions table used by Entrust to save permissions to the database.
    |
    */
    'permissions_table' => 'permissions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust permission_role Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the permission_role table used by Entrust to save relationship between permissions and roles to the database.
    |
    */
    'permission_role_table' => 'permission_role',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust assigned_roles Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the assigned_roles table used by Entrust to save assigned roles to the database.
    |
    */
    'assigned_roles_table' => 'assigned_roles',

);
```

I did a Config::get('entrust::key') in EntrustRole.php in the constructor on every single key just to see if it was just that one returning a blank array and it all returns a blank array. You can see the setup for Entrust at the url I posted earlier.

```
src
   config
      config.php
   Entrust
      EntrustRole.php
      AnotherClass.php
      etc...
```

This should be working am I wrong?

EDIT:
Here is how my providers array looks like:

```
'providers' => array(

        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
        'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider',
        'TwigBridge\ServiceProvider',
        'Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider',
        'Intellectproductions\Asset\AssetServiceProvider',
        'Intellectproductions\Verify\VerifyServiceProvider',
        'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',
        'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
        'Intellectproductions\Exemplary\ExemplaryServiceProvider',
        'Bunny\Providers\BunnyServiceProvider',
        'Bunny\Providers\UserServiceProvider',
        'Bunny\Providers\BreedServiceProvider',
        'Bunny\Providers\UserPetServiceProvider',
        'Bunny\Providers\ForumServiceProvider',
        'Bunny\Providers\RandomEventServiceProvider',
        'Bunny\Providers\TutorialServiceProvider'
    ),
```

I had to put the Entrust before my UserServiceProvider I believe.. but reorganizing it like this fixed the issue. I don't know if it's because my providers (Bunny\Providers) depend on the packages I have installed.. but hopefully this helps others. I think it's a tad silly, but oh well!

Comment: It still gives the same error... publishing the config is usually if you just want to change the values. It's optional so it should use their config by default..

Comment: did you add `'Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider'` to your `'providers'` array in `config/app.php`?

Comment: Yup I have the ServiceProvider and alias added.. =/

Comment: Hmm I didn't realize the order mattered... I put it a little further up in the list and it is working fine now? Can somebody explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: are you saying that it was at the end of the `providers` array and after moving it above some of the other providers you can now see that package's config values?

Comment: Yes... That's what happened.

Comment: can you update with what you have in your providers?

Comment: I updated it my original post!